# max length of text in a push Notification - Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification

I implemented a Windows Phone client which receives push notifications.

- What is the max size of the text that I can receive?

I cannot find it on google neither msdn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Push Notification Service limits the Nonfiction payload to 5KB.
 For more information click [here](http://blog.nanotoolkit.com/post/2013/10/27/Is-Apple-Push-Notification-Superior-to-Android-and-Windows-Phone-Push-Notification)